# HelloCardboard sample :sdk not visible in Gradle

Tags: android-ndk, google-cardboard, google-vr-sdk

I am trying to run the Google Cardboard sample by following their guide: https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/c/quickstart

However, I run into the same error mentioned in [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008108/how-to-fix-ndk-build-error-for-hellocardboard-sample/61025970#61025970). Their solution was:

> You should click the "assemble" option under ":sdk", not the one under ":hellocardboard-android".

As shown below:

[image]

The following is the image of my window. I don't have the `:hellocardboard-android` or `:sdk folders`, just `Tasks`.[image]

So, is this the right `assemble` to be running? I am not sure how to see the other folders mentioned. If you have any clarifying questions let me know!

My full error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':hellocardboard-android:externalNativeBuildDebug'.

> Build command failed.
> Error while executing process C:\Users\Jonah\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe with arguments {-C O:\Dordt University Campus\hellocardboard-android.cxx\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a cardboard_jni}
> ninja: Entering directory `O:\Dordt University Campus\hellocardboard-android.cxx\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a'

ninja: error: '../../../../libraries/jni/armeabi-v7a/libcardboard_api.so', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libcardboard_jni.so', missing and no known rule to make it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It appears the problem had to do with the path having spaces, moving the project caused the proper folders to appear in the Gradle window.